# Why don't redux actions "break" componentDidMount/useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, redux

A component will rerender when one of its props changes. That's sort of the whole point of React.

A component that's subscribed to a slice of Redux state will rerender when that state changes. That's sort of the whole point of Redux. And when you use the `connect` api, those slices of state are simply props, so it goes straight to my first point.

SO, what I'm wondering is:

```js
// only executes once, on mount, right?
componentDidMount() {
  this.something()
  this.props.someReduxActionThatModifiesAnotherPropInThisComponent()
  this.somethingElse()
}
```

Since the redux action changes the prop, and the component rerenders, I would think that `componentDidMount` has had its day and now it's done, and we'll never run `this.somethingElse()`.

**Obviously I am wrong about this. I know.** Can someone tell me what it is that makes this work? What is the whole flow here? I imagine the answer is maybe simply that a component *doesn't* rerender from inside CDM?

And is it any different in `useEffect`?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that `componentDidMount` only runs once. You are also correct that dispatching a redux action from within the method will trigger a re-render if your component is subscribed.

I think the confusion is about **when** a re-render occurs.

Updating state only informs React that a re-render is required, it does not pause execution and re-render immediately.

Because of this, the lifecycle method will complete execution of the entire method, and the run the scheduled re-render after.

This is related to why you also cannot use the updated state immediately after calling `this.setState` (or `dispatch` in Redux). Because the state is not updated instantly, you've only informed it that an update is required. Behind the scenes, React batches and performs the updates, and then determines what re-renders to perform.

The same is true about Function components and `useEffect`.

Answer (score 1):

**componentDidMount** runs only once during the mounting process. But even if you replaced componentDidMount with **componentDidUpdate**, it also wouldn't rerender before executing the whole function.

The reason to this is that it is actually up to React when to re-render. Sometimes, in situations like yours, React decides not to re-render the component immediately and postpone it.

A similar situation would be when same setState functions are called inside a method. The first setState call doesn't force an immediate re-render.